# MySQL database join on non-unique index

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

Every user has a local program in which he can manage

- cats (name, ...)
- feed (containing different types of feed: liquid, ...)
- a list "eat" holding information when a cat has eaten which type of feed (cat.nr, feed.nr, datetime)

These three tables am I going to import into a MySQL database.
Then I want a SELECT statement to get all eat-events with cat.name, feed.name and date

The problem is that every user might have assigned a cat.nr or feed.nr that is not unique (an other user might have used the same nr). This is not the primary index but I use this as INDEX for foreign key relationship, is this recommended?

To handle this, I am adding a userid field to every table and adding a user table itself (holding user.name, user.id) - How to accomplish a SQL statement returning all eat-events for a user with id 1 for example?

And is this a good approach at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you just need compound primary keys on the tables.  If, for instance, column cat_nr is unique for any given user_id (and user_id's are presumably unique) then combining them gives you your unique primary key.  You can join tables this way too (i.e. on both columns).

```
select *
    from eat_event e
    inner join feed f on f.feed_nr = e.feed_nr and f.user_id = e.user_id
```

The full query might look something like:

```
select e.event_date, e.event_type, u.user_name, c.cat_nr, f.feed_nr
    from eat_event e
    inner join feed f on f.feed_nr = e.feed_nr and f.user_id = e.user_id
    inner join cat c on c.cat_nr = e.cat_nr and f.user_id = e.user_id
    inner join [user] u on u.user_id = e.user_id
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: why do u have [user] in brackets?
imagine i want to do your full query but only for a specific user (id=1), is it correct to just add to your last line: "AND u.user_id = 1"  ?

Comment: @camel - The brackets around '[user]' is just for safety because 'user' is a reserved word in some versions of SQL.  The second part of your question is correct (mostly).  You would add `where u.user_id = 1` to get all eat_events for that user or `where u.user_id = 1 and e.event_date = '2018-02-17'` (depending on your date format) to get all events for that user on that day, etc.  Don't forget to 'Accept' this as the answer if it helps you.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! This is good answer and  now going to accept this. Still there is a question remaining because I think this problem is oftentimes with reference and joining on non unique keys... is there a general approach that is recommended?

Comment: Joining on non-unique columns is perfectly acceptable, you just get multiple matches - sometimes you might want that.  In this case though, the heart of the problem (primary key or not) was that we didn't know which cat was which without also knowing who the user was.  Because the Cat and Feed tables are essentially look-up tables, it follows that this combination that uniquely identifies each cat or food is also the natural primary key.

Comment: Now that I want to improve my project, I thought it is a good idea to use foreign keys. Thanks again that you have perfectly understood my issue. Maybe you also know how to correctly set up foreign keys with restrictions? As you already mentioned, the combination is the actual natural key...